# Unable to define a ForeignKey field in Django models

Tags: django, django-models

I am not able to define `ForeignKey` relation from `UsersGroups` model with the other two models `Roles` and `Users`. It throws an error -

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 786, in __init__
    to._meta.model_name
AttributeError: type object 'Roles' has no attribute '_meta'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/eitan-app/users_and_auth/models.py", line 31, in <module>
    class UsersGroups():
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/eitan-app/users_and_auth/models.py", line 33, in UsersGroups
    group_id = models.ForeignKey(Roles, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank= False)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 792, in __init__
    RECURSIVE_RELATIONSHIP_CONSTANT,
AssertionError: ForeignKey(<class 'users_and_auth.models.Roles'>) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'
```

```
class Roles():
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=False)


class Users(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    """
    This model is used to store user login credential and profile information.
    It's a custome user model but used for Django's default authentication.
    """

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pictures/', max_length=None, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    # defing a custome user manager class for the custome user model.
    objects = managers.UserManager()

    # using email a unique identity for the user and it will also allow user to use email while logging in.
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'


class UsersGroups():
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    group_id = models.ForeignKey(Roles, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank= False)
```

As stated in documentation I have provided `model name` as a first arguments to the `ForeignKey` and have also passed an argument `on_delete=models.CASCADE`

Comment: try user = .....  not user_id = ...  django internally converts user to user_id  to the database level  and also after you create the models you meed to run  the commands to update the database  python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate  the docs about model relationships  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: Your `class Roles():` does not extend django's `models.Model`. That's why you are getting invalid `ForeignKey`

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis It isn't a problem. Naming it `user_id` will simply result in `user_id_id` in database. Which can be prevented by using `db_column` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Roles` class *(and `UsersGroups` too)* is not defined properly, it need to extend Django `Model` class in order to a valid model and be used as a `ForeignKey`.

```
class Roles(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=False)
```

I also want to mention about a few other problems with your code.
1) Don't name your models in a plural form. Django expect's them to be in a singular form.
2) When you define a `ForeignKey`, don't use `xxx_id` as a name. Django automatically creates `xxx_id` attribute for your model so you will end up with `xxx_id_id`.

So having this in mind your code should really look like this:

```
class Role(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=False)


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    This model is used to store user login credential and profile information.
    It's a custome user model but used for Django's default authentication.
    """

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pictures/', max_length=None, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    # defing a custome user manager class for the custome user model.
    objects = managers.UserManager()

    # using email a unique identity for the user and it will also allow user to use email while logging in.
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'


class UserGroup(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank= False)
```